# How to share the view layout of a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

Basically until now I create a `ViewController` in the Storyboard, set its class in the identity inspector and implement the connections and behaviour in the class.

Now I have two `ViewControllers` (`ViewControllerFoo` and `ViewControllerBar`), both are visually the same, but the information and the implementations of the actions of the buttons are different. So I want to create a `BaseViewController`, with the view creation and common implementation and override some methods in the `ViewControllerFoo` and `ViewControllerBar`

If possible I'd like to keep both `ViewControllers` in the StoryBoard in order to create the segues that launches each one of them visually

How can I do this?

Note: I'm starting with **iOS** development.

Answer (score 1):

View layout is something that works with view not with view controller.

You can create a simple .xib (or view) file and draw your layout here.

After that add this view to controller or specify that view as main view of this controller.

Or you can create a view class and place all elements programmatically.

Just think about storyboard as 'navigation' utility not 'view layout' utility.

Note: too many views on storyboard speed down your computer and look too ugly.

Draw view in xib to reuse it or create custom views classes/clusters to implement interesting UX/UI effects